# Cardinity API with Curl Oauth1

Tags: php, curl, oauth

Hi can anyone help me with Cardinity API.

https://developers.cardinity.com/api/v1/?shell#authentication

I want to auth with Curl PHP, but it's not working. I receive error from cardinity.

There is an error code below.

> { "type": "https://developers.cardinity.com/api/v1/#401", "title": "Unauthorized", "status": 401, "detail": "Inadequate OAuth consumer credentials." }

Here it's my code.

```
<?php

$consumer_key = "asd";
$consumer_sec = "adefg";

$url = 'https://api.cardinity.com/v1/payments';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$timestamp = time();

$nonce = md5($timestamp);

//Generate Signature

$base = 'POST&'.$url.'&oauth_consumer_key='.$consumer_key.'&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp='.$timestamp.'&oauth_nonce='.$nonce.'&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_token=';

$base = rawurlencode($base);

$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base, rawurlencode($consumer_sec), true));

//

$headers = array();

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$headers[] = 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.$consumer_key.'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="'.$timestamp.'", oauth_nonce="'.$nonce.'", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="", oauth_signature="'.$signature.'"';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Seems like you are not authorized. Did you grant the relevant permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Your OAuth signature is not generated correctly. Your OAuth composite key is wrong. Here is the documentation for HMACSha1
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.2

gist: The composite key that u are suppose to use needs to have both client shared secret and token shared secret. With an "&" in the middle.

isntead of

```
rawurlencode($consumer_sec)
```

if your token is blank, for the third parameter of hash_hmac u need to use

```
rawurlencode($consumer_sec). "&"
```

Here is a full example of  using cardinity api via curl

```
<?php


$cardinityConsumerKey = 'test_jhcm1kuiowcs2s9dj03vryr4v8yf4e';
$cardinityConsumerSecret = 'uczqtwmhh2dj1m2vkulspssqisqc2qzjo8v23auqssux4opvag';
$timeStamp = time();
$nonce = $timeStamp. '123';

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params){
    $paramStrings = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $paramStrings[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }

    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $paramStrings));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth){
    $headerString = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";

    $headerString .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $headerString;
}


$postRequest = array(
    "amount" => "100.00",
    "currency" => "EUR",
    "order_id" => $nonce,
    "country" => "LT",
    "payment_method" => "card",
    "payment_instrument" => array(
        "pan" => "4111111111111111",
        "exp_year" => 2021,
        "exp_month" => 11,
        "cvc" => "521",
        "holder" => "Not Mike Dough"
    ),    
);

$oAuthParams = [
    'oauth_consumer_key'        => $cardinityConsumerKey,
    'oauth_nonce'               => $nonce,
    'oauth_signature_method'    => "HMAC-SHA1",
    'oauth_timestamp'           => $timeStamp, 
    //'oauth_token'               => '',
    'oauth_version'             => '1.0',
    
];


$baseString = buildBaseString('https://api.cardinity.com/v1/payments', 'POST', $oAuthParams);
$compositeKey = rawurlencode($cardinityConsumerSecret) . '&';
$rawHash = hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $compositeKey , true);
$signature = base64_encode($rawHash);


$oAuthParams['oauth_signature'] = $signature;
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    buildAuthorizationHeader($oAuthParams), 
    //'Expect:',
);


$cURLConnection = curl_init('https://api.cardinity.com/v1/payments');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postRequest));
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

// $apiResponse - available data from the API request
$jsonArrayResponse = json_decode($apiResponse, TRUE);

if($jsonArrayResponse['status'] == 'approved'){
    echo "<h1>Payment Successful</h1>";
}else{
    echo "<h1>Payment Failed</h1>";
}

echo "<pre>";
echo "HEADERS #" . print_r($headers, true);
echo "<br/>";
echo "POSTDATA #" . print_r($postRequest, true);
echo "<br/>";
echo "RESPONSE #" . print_r($jsonArrayResponse, true);
echo "</pre>";
```